# Default Scope - Sort model by 2 columns where one is an association - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting, model

I have two classes `Building` and `Room`. I want to sort my `Room` model by the building's `name` attribute and then by the room's `room_number` attribute. This is essentially what I want to do:

```
class Room
  belongs_to :building

  default_scope :order => 'building.name, room_number' # Doesn't work.
end
```

I just don't know how to get the association to work. Is there a way to do this in Rails?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to JOIN the `buildings` table before you can reference in the order condition.

```
default_scope :joins => :building, :order => 'buildings.name, room_number'
```